# How to remove folder subtree from a git repository? Is that possible?

Tags: git

I want to remove a sub-folder from a git repository.

I have used git -rm -r  and it removed the folders both from the local filesystem; and then I did a git-add followed by a git-commit.

Please let me know why the deleted folder is still there when I do clone?

Regards,
M

Comment: Why are you _cloning_ at this point, as you are already working with the repo?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to run `git add` after `git rm`. I just replicated what you said you did and the deleted directory did not show up in a (local) clone of the repo.

Maybe you forgot to `git push` your changes? Are you using a remote repo?

Oh, and by the way: You can only really delete something from a git repo if you rewrite the history, using `git rebase` for example. Otherwise it will always be present in the history and can also be recovered by checking out an earlier version.

Comment: Haha, I think back then the subtree command was not yet available. Your comment also doesn't make any sense. It's only about deleting a folder. A git subtree is something else.

Comment: git subtree came out in 2012. And subtree (as opposed to subfolder or subdirectory) is part of the title of this question. Your reply helps clarify. thanks!

Comment: could you edit this with a note about subfolder or subdirectory. Wanting to vote this up. But stackoverflow says it won't unless post is edited